# Como puedo delimitar una tabla por cantidad de filas en (reportlab + django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pdf, reportlab

Hola a todos: El problema puntual que tengo es que, estoy exportando a pdf con reportlab en django unos teléfonos que tengo en BD, los estoy exportando en una tabla por la comodidad de manejo de los datos. El asunto es que cuando los exporto la tabla es mayor de una página y no he podido dar con la solución para cortar la tabla en n filas por página automáticamente. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería. Saludos
Les dejo el view.py

```
class ReporteTelefonosPDF(View):
    def header(self, pdf):
        ArchivoImagen = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/test.jpg'
        pdf.drawImage(ArchivoImagen, 400, 750, 120, 90, preserveAspectRatio=True)
        # Establecemos el tamaño de letra en 16 y el tipo de letra Helvetica
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 16)
        # Dibujamos una cadena en la ubicación X,Y especificada
        pdf.drawString(50, 790, u"DATEC")
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 14)
        pdf.drawString(80, 770, u"REPORTE DE TELEFONIA")

    def tabla(self, pdf, y):
        # Creamos una tupla de encabezados para neustra tabla
        encabezados = ('Entidad', 'Nombre y Apellidos', 'Cargo', 'Tel Celular', 'Tel Fijo', 'Ext', 'Correo')
        # Creamos una lista de tuplas que van a contener a las personas
        # Estilos de la tabla para cabeceras y datos
        estiloHoja = getSampleStyleSheet()
        thread = estiloHoja["Normal"]
        thread.alignment = TA_CENTER
        tbody = estiloHoja["BodyText"]
        tbody.alignment = TA_LEFT

        detalles = [(telefonia.entidad, telefonia.nombre, telefonia.cargo, telefonia.numero_cell, telefonia.numero_fijo, telefonia.extencion,
                     telefonia.correo_electronico) for telefonia in telefonia.objects.all()]
        # Establecemos el tamaño de cada una de las columnas de la tabla
        detalle_orden = Table([encabezados] + detalles, colWidths=[3 * cm, 4 * cm, 5 * cm, 1.5 * cm, 2 * cm, 0.5 * cm, 4 * cm], rowHeights=0.5* cm)
        # Aplicamos estilos a las celdas de la tabla
        detalle_orden.setStyle(TableStyle(
            [
                # La primera fila(encabezados) va a estar centrada
                ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                # Los bordes de todas las celdas serán de color negro y con un grosor de 1
                ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
                # El tamaño de las letras de cada una de las celdas será de 7
                ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 7),
            ]
        ))
        # Establecemos el tamaño de la hoja que ocupará la tabla
        detalle_orden.wrapOn(pdf, 800, 600)
        # Definimos la coordenada donde se dibujará la tabla
        detalle_orden.drawOn(pdf, 10, y-58)


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Indicamos el tipo de contenido a devolver, en este caso un pdf
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        #La clase io.BytesIO permite tratar un array de bytes como un fichero binario, se utiliza como almacenamiento temporal
        buffer = BytesIO()
        #Canvas nos permite hacer el reporte con coordenadas X y Y
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

        #Llamo al método cabecera donde están definidos los datos que aparecen en la cabecera del reporte.
        self.header(pdf)
        y = 15
        self.tabla(pdf, y)

        #Con show page hacemos un corte de página para pasar a la siguiente
        pdf.showPage()
        pdf.save()
        pdf = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        response.write(pdf)
        return response
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero esto te sirva, tuve el mismo problema en un sistema de reportes y no encontré como hacerlo, asi que lo implementé, es simplemente paginar la información que será añadida en la tabla, teniendo en cuenta la altura que ocupa cada celda de la tabla, la lógica es la siguiente: Primero calculas la cantidad de pixeles que existen desde el inicio de la página(en este caso, el inicio es el final de la pagina, como mismo en un sistema de coordenadas XY para los valores positivos solamente)(parte inferior izquierda), hasta el tope de la pagina donde empezaras a mostrar la tabla, luego divides esa cantidad por el tamaño de la celda de la tabla(grid) y te dará la cantidad de celdas posibles a crear en esa hoja, luego solo es iterar la lista de valores teniendo en cuente la cantidad resultante de la división. Mira el código aquí:

```
def tabla(self, pdf, partes, y):
    width, height = A4

    headers = ('Unidad', 'Fecha', 'Produccion', 'Real', 'Plan', 'Cantidad', 'TOTAL')
    items = [(item.unidad,
              item.fecha,
              item.produccion,
              item.real,
              item.plan,
              item.cant,
              item.total) for item in partes]
    table = Table([headers] + items, colWidths=80)
    table.setStyle(TableStyle(
        [
            ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
            ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
            ('ALING', (0, 0), (3, 0), 'CENTER'),
            ('GRID', (0, 0), (6, -1), 1, colors.black),
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightslategray),
            ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 10),
        ]
    ))
    table.wrapOn(pdf, width, height)
    table.drawOn(pdf, 20, y)
    pdf.showPage()

def get(self, request):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = Reporte'
    buff = BytesIO()
    pdf = canvas.Canvas(buff, pagesize=portrait(A4))

    partes = Parte_Diario_Unidad.objects.filter(**filtros).order_by('unidad', 'fecha')
    ####################################################################################
# esta es la parte de la paginacion
    max_len = 25 # se define la cantidad por pagina(previamente calculado)
    heigth_data = len(partes)  # se obtiene la longitud de la lista de datos a mostrar

    if heigth_data <= max_len: # si la cantidad de elementos de la lista es menor que la cantidad definida por paginas, en este caso 25 se pasa la lista tal cual
        partes = list(partes)
        self.tabla(pdf, partes, y=600 - (len(partes) * 18))

    elif heigth_data > max_len:
        partes = list(partes)[::-1] # esto es solo para invertir la lista
        pages_needed = math.ceil(float(heigth_data / max_len)) #se obtiene la cantidad de paginas necesarias a partir de la cantidad de datos en la lista
        iterator = max_len # se guarda el valor en un iterador
        for page in range(0, int(pages_needed)): # esta parte se explica por si sola
            record = []
            if max_len < len(partes):
                iterator = max_len
            else:
                iterator = len(partes)
            for i in range(0, iterator):
                record.append(partes.pop())

            self.set_page_number(pdf, number_page=(page + 1)) # una funcion que hice para a;adir el numero de pagina
            self.tabla(pdf, record, y=600 - (len(record) * 18.3)) # aqui y es la coordenada y donde empezara a dibujar la tabla

    pdf.save()
    pdf = buff.getvalue()
    buff.close()
    response.write(pdf)

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Leandro PERFECTA su respuesta, con su ejemplo resolví el problema. A lo que el código me queda así.

```
    class ReporteTelefonosPDF(View):

    def header(self, pdf):
        ArchivoImagen = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/test.jpg'
        pdf.drawImage(ArchivoImagen, 600, 500, 120, 90, preserveAspectRatio=True)
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 16)
        pdf.drawString(15, 550, u"DATEC")
        pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 14)
        pdf.drawString(65, 530, u"REPORTE DE TELEFONIA")

    def tabla(self, pdf, telefonia, y):
        width, height = A4
        flag = True
        encabezados = ('Compañía', 'Nombre y Apellidos', 'Cargo', 'Tel Celular', 'Tel Fijo', 'Ext', 'Correo')
        detalles = [(
            items.compañía,
            items.nombre,
            items.cargo,
            items.numero_cell,
            items.numero_fijo,
            items.extencion,
            items.correo_electronico) for items in telefonia]
        detalle_orden = Table([encabezados] + detalles,
                              colWidths=[3 * cm, 4.5 * cm, 6.8 * cm, 1.5 * cm, 6 * cm, 1 * cm, 5.2* cm],
                              rowHeights=0.5 * cm
                              )
        detalle_orden.setStyle(TableStyle(
            [
                ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
                ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 7.5),
            ]
        ))
        detalle_orden.wrapOn(pdf, width, height)
        detalle_orden.drawOn(pdf, 20, y)
        pdf.showPage()

    def get(self, request):
        y = 600
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = Reporte'
        buff = BytesIO()
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(buff, pagesize=landscape(A4))

        tel = telefonia.objects.all().order_by('UEB')
        self.header(pdf)

        ####################################################################################
        # esta es la parte de la paginacion
        max_len = 28 
        heigth_data = len(tel)
          if heigth_data <= max_len:  
            partes = list(tel)
            self.header(pdf)
            self.tabla(pdf, partes, y=850 - (len(partes) * 28))

        elif heigth_data > max_len:
            partes = list(tel)[::-1] 
            pages_needed = math.ceil(float(
                heigth_data / max_len)) 
            iterator = max_len  
            for page in range(0, int(pages_needed)):  
                record = []
                if max_len < len(partes):
                    iterator = max_len
                else:
                    iterator = len(partes)
                for i in range(0, iterator):
                    record.append(partes.pop())
                if iterator > 0:
                    self.header(pdf)
                    self.tabla(pdf, record, y=850 - (len(record) * 28))  
                else:
                    self.tabla(pdf, record, y=850 - (len(record) * 28)) 
                    self.header(pdf)

        pdf.save()
        pdf = buff.getvalue()
        buff.close()
        response.write(pdf)
        return response
```

Nuevamente muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Que bueno que te sirviera el ejemplo. Suerte en su proyecto. Saludos